# WordPress Conditional Logic for Menu ID

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to have a conditional logic based upon the current nav_menu / menu id. For instance, I have multiple menus and I would like to have show or hide a specific div container based upon the menu that is shown.

[image]

So if any certain page, for instance, is using the menu with id 27 (nav-menus.php?action=edit&menu=27) then I would like to show a specific div container and hide it in case the specific page is using menu id 26.

Is this somehow possible? I've tried to make a little research on the subject but can't find anything in relation to it. Some expert help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can access menu variable and base your logic on it.

```
<?php
if($menu_item->ID ==  "27")
{
//Show div here
}
else
{
//Show something else here
}
?>
```

Comment: Oh wow great, I've got to try that. Thank you very much

Comment: Try $menu_item->ID;